# How do you say ‘liquidity’ (in the sense of ‘easily convertible to cash’) in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are two meanings of ‘[liquidity](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-liquidity.html)’, namely, financial solvency, and that of being easily convertible to cash. It is the latter sense that I am asking about.

Of Benson, Wells, Vikivortaro, Vikipedio, ReVo and Sonja, only Wells and Vikivortaro seem to address this sense. They both offer the same translation: ‘likideco’ – yes, without the ‘v’ that one would expect. It seems like a typo, and yet it occurs in two (presumably) independent sources (or, was it a typo in Wells that got copied into Vikivortaro?). Anyway, how should ‘liquidity’ in the sense of ‘easily convertible to cash’ be rendered in Esperanto?

Answer (score 3):

As the official word *solventa* means "pagokapabla", capable of paying, and of course qualifies a natural or legal person, I would propose for the liquid capital ***solventiga***, because according to my (layman) understanding liquid capital is such capital which makes the owner solvent.

Another possibility would be *neligita* (in the meaning 2 of ligi according to PIV: "limigi ies liberan agadon") or *neblokumita*.

EDIT: I just looked it up in the huge German/Esperanto dictionaries by Krause. He also has *likida*, so this is a real word, not a typo, I found it also used a few times on the Internet. But I don't know whether it also has the two meanings of English *liquid*. As my proposals above rather aim at the first meaning, a clear for the second meaning would be ***kontant/ig/ebl/a***.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Minnaja’s [Vocabolario Italiano-Esperanto](http://www.swahili.it/glossword/index.php?a=term&d=2&t=150391) you see that somebody (surely not a *bonlingvisto*) came up with *likva* (a [phase of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid)) ≠ *likvida* (in [linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_consonant)) ≠ *likida* (convertible to cash.) I usually don’t agree with extreme *bonlingvistoj,* but I also disagree with such proliferation of similar-sounding roots. Just as *likva konsonanto* is OK with me, ***pagipov(ec)o*** and ***kontantigebl(ec)o*** are the forms I’d recommend for the two meanings of *liquidity* we are talking about here.

**Edit:** I googled ***likida*** and (after pruning thousands of spurious hits) I found that either it appears only in dictionaries or I have pruned too much. In any case, it is an extremely rare word, not really alive. On the contrary, ***kontantigebl**** gives a dozen of genuine hits, not all with this precise meaning, but all close to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think words like *monigebla*, *monigebleco* are quite fit for your meaning ("cashable"). Also *vendebleco*, or *tujvendebleco* are good for that.